# How to tell thread stack usage from Python?

Tags: python, memory-management, freebsd

I'd like to log the stack usage of a long-running thread (that is, one that is active during the whole life of the application), how can I do it? Something like "xxxxKB used" would be enough.

(Python 2.6.6, FreeBSD 8.2-RC3)

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified FreeBSD, the [`resource`](http://docs.python.org/library/resource.html#resource-usage) module that comes with Python (but only works for Unix-y environments) might be helpful.  Specifically, `resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_BOTH)` provides will give you the resource usage of that process and all child processes.

It would look like you'd be interested in the following:

```
    ru_maxrss   maximum resident set size
    ru_ixrss    shared memory size
    ru_idrss    unshared memory size
    ru_isrss    unshared stack size
```

Comment: On my system RUSAGE_BOTH isn't defined... I'll try with RUSAGE_SELF, thanks :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but... Let's say I get these values: `max = 42928, ix = 127920, id = 249936, is = 15872`, well, what do they mean? :) The FreeBSD man page at http://www.manpages.info/freebsd/getrusage.2.html says that the i*rss values are "expressed in units of kilobytes * ticks-of-execution"... So it looks like getting to my "xxxxKb used" isn't very straightforward.. Is getrusage the only way?